# Is the asymptotic value (at high energy) of alpha strong null or non null?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

If it is non null then why do we say that there is asymptotic freedom. Freedom would mean alpha strong equal zero

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/subatomic-particle/Colour#ref367767

Comment: are you thinking of the unification plot?https://www.britannica.com/science/subatomic-particle/Colour#ref367767  I expect if/when a unified force is defined there will be one coupling constant. The term asymptotic freedom is used to explain that quarks are "free" within the hadrons as they can be "infinitly"close.

Comment: sorry, this is  the link I wanted https://www-project.slac.stanford.edu/e158/running-unification.html

Comment: Yes I speak about this but if the asymptot (y value) of the curve alpha strong = f(energy) at infinite value of energy is non null then there is no freedom. So what is the asymptot ?

Comment: The asymptotic behavior goes as r-> 0, i.e the distance between two colored particles approaches zero. The behavior with energy is not expected to go  to zero as the unified forces model comes in, as the links say. At large distances it is very large attraction at small distances goes to wards zero.

Comment: So do I understand that for a unified theory  we don t really know if there would be asymptotic freedom ?

Comment: In the unified theory all forces are one force, and depending on the model, will have one coupling constant. There is no definite model at the moment. For example in cosmology the quark gluon plasma is treated as free particles, see here  https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter2.pdf